# GUI development with Glade/FreeBasic - missing gtkwidget.bi

Tags: glade, geany

Trying GUI development with combination of Glade, FreeBasic and Geany, compilation fails because no gtkwidget.bi include file can be located. In fact this file is missing from my computer (Ubuntu Precise Pangolin)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install all of the dependancies with glade, freebasic and geany?  If not then try and go to you software center and install al packages / dependancies that come with these pieces of software

If you try using this:

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential libc6-dev libncurses-dev libgpmg1-dev libx11-dev libxpm-dev libxrandr-dev libglitz-glx1-dev
```

just looked on internet for you and theres that ^ piece of code and also this link here :

[FreeBasic installation video for Ubuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=henTW2vST3I)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Freebasic is missing from the software center. Uninstalled glade & geany (installed with apt-get installed) and reinstalled with ALL plugins. "gtk/gtkwidget.bi" is still missing.

Comment: if you look at my previous answer i have just added some info for you try using the command thats there  (you will need to go into terminal)

you can also watch the video (the link provided) to help you out a little.

Comment: Thanks again. Tried the install command (I think you meant sudo apt-get install...). libglitz-glx1-dev is unavailable. The www.freebasic.net (as shown in the video) does not exist, only a sourceforge site, unfortunately there are only gzipped files and no references to headers, etc. I am giving up, will use Gambas instead of this complicated procedure.